# Need help regarding cin.get and cin.putback

Tags: c++, get, cin

I am very new to programming and was looking at this bit of code, trying to understand how it works. My understanding is, that the start of each run of the while loop the program waits for an input, and if that input is allowed the loop is run. Is that correct? If it is, how come the program prints out the '$' if a '!' is typed in, seeing as how in that case the cout command in the else case is not activated?

```
int main() {
 char ch;
 cout << "enter a phrase: ";
 while ( cin.get(ch) ) {
     if (ch == '!') cin.putback('$');
     else cout << ch;
     while (cin.peek() == `#') cin.ignore(1,'#');
  }
 return 0;
 }
```

Output: enter a phrase: Now!is#the!time#for!fun#!
Now$isthe$timefor$fun$

Comment: I'm no C++ expert, but I guess `cin.putback` replaces the last typed character in the `cin` stream. It indeed has nothing to do with `cout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/putback/) for `putback` method:

> istream& putback (char c);
>
> Put character back
>
> Attempts to decrease the current location in the
>   stream by one character, making the last character extracted from the
>   stream once again available to be extracted by input operations.

If the program reads a `'!'` character, it puts back to the stream a `'$'` character, which is read at the next loop iteration and printed.

Comment: So if i understand you correctly, then cin.putback('$') will sort of say that the next time that a character in my program is supposed to be read in, that character will be '$'?

Comment: @ElDuderino Yes. But note that (from the same documentation): the `putback` behavior depends on the particular stream buffer object associated to the stream. Different types of buffers may either fail, be ignored, or overwrite the character at that position.